# One-Time Welcome Screen Is not Working

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

So I wanted to create a one-time intro screen to my application by using `SharedPreferences` in an answer that I found on another post. At first, the code *seemed* to be working, but it isn't, ***now.*** Can anybody tell me what is going on?

WelcomeActivity.java (Launcher activity):

```
package org.reliefdev.reliefdevedworking;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    final String showWelcomeScreenString = "showWelcome";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);


        Button getStarted = findViewById(R.id.getStartedBtn);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final Boolean welcomeScreenShown = prefs.getBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, false);

        getStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (welcomeScreenShown) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, LoginReliefAccountActivity.class));
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, true);
                    editor.apply();

                } else if(!welcomeScreenShown){
                    startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, LoginReliefAccountActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried running the app again after clearing its data in settings?

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I made a silly mistake in the code. I put the `SharedPreferences` code INSIDE the OnClickListener. If I reverse that, so if the sharedprefs boolean is`true`, THEN set an OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Init :final Boolean welcomeScreenShown = prefs.getBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, true);
AS True. After the first run make it False:
  editor.putBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, false);

```
 public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences prefs;
final String showWelcomeScreenString = "showWelcome";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);


    Button getStarted = findViewById(R.id.getStartedBtn);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(WelcomeActivity.this);
    final Boolean welcomeScreenShown = prefs.getBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, true);

    getStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (welcomeScreenShown) {
                startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, LoginReliefAccountActivity.class));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, false);
                editor.apply();

            } else if(!welcomeScreenShown){
                startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, LoginReliefAccountActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I actually had it set true then change to false after the button had been pressed. It wasn't working so I tried switching it up and seeing if it would work. But it didn't.

Comment: If you click on the button in the welcome screen , it takes you to the login screen. That means that if you restart the application, does it go straight to login?

Comment: no, If you going to go straightly to login activity add this in onCreate: 'welcomeScreenShown = prefs.getBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, true);
 if(!welcomeScreenShown){
                startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, LoginReliefAccountActivity.class));
            }'    i'm not sure about if(!welcomeScreenShown) or if(welcomeScreenShown), please check it

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences prefs;
 boolean welcomeScreenShown ;
final String showWelcomeScreenString = "showWelcome";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button getStarted = (Button) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    welcomeScreenShown = prefs.getBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, true);

    getStarted.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "welcomeScreenShown:"+welcomeScreenShown, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("welcomeScreenShown:"+welcomeScreenShown);
            if (welcomeScreenShown) {
                welcomeScreenShown = false;

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(showWelcomeScreenString, false);
                editor.apply();
                //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginReliefAccountActivity.class));

            } else if(!welcomeScreenShown){
               // System.out.println("welcomeScreenShown:"+welcomeScreenShown);
               // startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginReliefAccountActivity.class));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}